# jQuery autocomplete : set to the links the title

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

If I do :

```
var countryList = [
    "London",
    "Milan",
    "New York"
];

$("#divDest").autocomplete({
    source: countryList
});
```

the plugins will render somethings like this :

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 21; top: 243px; left: 768px; display: none; width: 131px;">
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
        <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">London</a>
    </li>

    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
        <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Milan</a>
    </li>

    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
        <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">New York</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Well, suppose I'd like to put on the links not only the name of the country, but, in the `title` attribute some other info (for example, the ID for each country). Such as :

```
<a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" title="country_3523">New York</a>
```

How can I do it with that plugins?

Answer (score 0):

```
  _renderItem: function( ul, item) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( $( "<a></a>" ).text( item.label ).attr('title', item.title) )
            .appendTo( ul );
    },
```

Comment: in jqueru ui u need to change this query. u r asking how to add title to hyperlink?

Comment: Uhm... I don't like to generate links, and then edit them (a lot of overhead). Is it not possible render them also with html+title?

Comment: where this 'country_3523' value come from?

Comment: well, Its a info that I want to give to the plugins :) Such as `{"New York", "3523"}` ?